# Множественный выбор php

Tags: javascript, php

Задача сделать через модальное окно добавление цитат. Автор, дата должны подставляться автоматом. Теги - выбираться не более 3х. Сейчас конкретно стоит вопрос с тегами. как дату и имя подставить потом это я сделаю, но как сделать выбор нескольких тегов из списка и поттом записывать их в бд? Я не понимаю. Понимаю, что надо сделать как-то через массив, но у меня не выходит. Прошу помочь разобраться. Еще вопрос как потом это запихнуть в бд.. Я новичок, поэтому прошу не судить строго..:)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть 3 таблицы. Прилагаю скрин. код страницы createquote.php:

```
<!-- Триггер/Открыть модальный -->
    <button id="myBtn">Открыть</button>
<form action="" method="post">
    <!-- Модальный -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Модальное содержание -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>Создание цитаты</p>
        <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Цитата:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
            <textarea name="shortdescription" class="form-control" id="shortdescription" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Теги:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">                  
        <select name="check[]" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="tags_id">
        <?php
        $sql = mysqli_query($connect, 'SELECT `id`, `Name` FROM `tags`');
        while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
            {
            echo "\t\t<option value=\"{$result['id']}\">{$result['Name']}</option>\n";//тут надо как-то сделать выбор нескольких тегов. То что сейчас - мои попытки..
            }
        ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Сохранить" name="ok" class = "l"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

js:

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
 
// кнопка, которая открывает модальное окно
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
 
// Получить элемент <span>, который закрывает модальное окно
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
 
// Когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку, открываем модальное окно
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
 
// Когда пользователь нажимает на <span> (x), закрываем модальное окно
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
 
// Когда пользователь щелкает в любом месте за пределами модального окна, закрываем его
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: Если у вас теги уже в массиве, переберите массив тем же foreach и для каждого значения из массива сделайте `echo` с тегами option. Для начала их хотя бы распечатайте все. Хотя я бы пользовал скорее всего checkbox, у которых было бы одно имя, но разные значения.

Comment: Так он и перебирается и выводится. просто нет общего выбора, как его сделать - тоже вопрос. как чекбоксы - хороший вариант, вы правы. сейчас посмотрю... но я понятия не имею как потом записать несколько значений в таблицу..

Comment: Простите за грубость, но вас в гугле или яндексе забанили? )) При поиске "html select множественный выбор" первая же  ссылка - http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml5/formy/pole-so-spiskom?ysclid=l8n4gxojmy588070039 выдаёт решение `<select name="select" size="10" multiple>`

Comment: К слову, если тегов до фига, но надо записывать только три - придётся реализовать либо на javascript - чтобы пользователь вообще не мог больше трёх позиций отметить, либо на php - всё равно, сколько наотмечал пользователь, записывать только первые три. Когда форма отправит данные, вы получите по сути тот же массив.